# uninstall windows server 2008 and add disk space to ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have windows 2008 and Ubuntu 12.04 installed. I want to remove windows server 2008 and add space to Ubuntu 10.04?How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of making alterations to the primary hard drive is "Make a backup".

The Second rule of making alterations to the primary hard drive is "Make a backup".

There are three ways to do this, you can delete the windows drive using Gparted then expand the Ubuntu partition to include to resulting empty space.  I'm not sure how well this will work as I have never done it that way round. (I have moved Ubuntu and expanded windows and Ubuntu partitions to fill the drive).  Give it a try, if it all goes wrong you can go back to your backup.

Or, you can delete the windows partition and reformat the space as ext4 and mount it for use in your Ubuntu file system.

Finally, re-install with the latest version and copy the settings from your backup.

Did I mention that you should do a backup?

Comment: Thank you sir for your response.I formatted a drive in to ext4. Now how to add it to Ubuntu 12.04??? Is it already in the Ubuntu??